# How to check the selected month is the current month

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have a dropdown on month. What I want is when select current month, the data will display and when select previous month or incoming month, the data should display 'N/A'. Currently, the data is display in a solid gauge (speedometer).Below is the code

```
    //Dropdown
        <h3 class="box-title">
           Month:
          <input type="month" name="month" id="month" value="<?=date('Y-m')?>" class="onchange">
        </h3>

//Script
$(function () {
    $("body").on( "change",'.onchange', function( event ) {
        $("#loading1").show();
        $("#loading2").show();
        $("#loading3").show();
        $("#loading4").show();
        $("#loading5").show();
        $('#generation').DataTable().ajax.reload();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/lookup/getPlantLoading/",
            data: { 
                campus: $('#campus').val(), 
                month: $('#month').val() 
            },
            success: function(data){
                chartPlantLoading(data);
                $("#loading1").hide();
            }
        });

//Chart 1
function chartPlantLoading(data) {
    var gaugeOptions = {
        chart: { type: 'solidgauge' },
        title: null,
        pane: {
            center: ['50%', '65%'],
            size: '100%',
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: {
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.defaultOptions.legend.backgroundColor || '#EEE',
                innerRadius: '60%',
                outerRadius: '100%',
                shape: 'arc'
            }
        },
        exporting: {
            enabled: true
        },

        tooltip: {
            enabled: false
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis: {
            stops: [
                [0.1, '#DF5353'], // green
                [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
                [0.9, '#55BF3B'] // red
            ],
            lineWidth: 0,
            tickWidth: 0,
            minorTickInterval: null,
            tickAmount: 2,
            title: {
                y: -70
            },
            labels: {
                y: 16
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            solidgauge: {
                dataLabels: {
                    y: 5,
                    borderWidth: 0,
                    useHTML: true
                }
            }
        }
    };


    if(data.data != 0.0){
        Highcharts.chart('plant_loading', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{
            name: 'Plant Loading',
            // data: [80],
            data: data.data,
            dataLabels: {
                format:

                    '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                    '<span style="font-size:25px">N/A</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">%</span>' +
                    '</div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }
        }]
    }));
    }
    else{
        Highcharts.chart('plant_loading', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        credits: { enabled: false },
        series: [{
            name: 'Plant Loading',
            // data: [80],
            data: data.data,
            dataLabels: {
                format:

                    '<div style="text-align:center">' +
                    '<span style="font-size:25px">{y}</span><br/>' +
                    '<span style="font-size:12px;opacity:0.4">%</span>' +
                    '</div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            }
        }]
    }));
    }
}
```

The data is already show a correct data, but how do I check whether the selected month is the current month and set when user choose previous month or incoming month, the meter will display 'N/A'?

Below is the current look of the speedometer

[image: The image of current speedometer when in current month or other months]

Comment: where do you want to check the month?

Comment: if possible, I would like to do it in blade instead of controller. Is it possible? I am new to PHP javascript & Laravel